# I have two button click counters in one html page using Javascript. I want to total the two clicks in a new span

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have modified a click counter to have two count buttons each with a reset button. I have also added a total to the bottom of my page. The ask is this: I need to add 1 to the total at the bottom when the button titled "Verified Videos" is pressed. I then need to add 1 to the total when the button titled "Document Count" reaches 9 then 18 then 27 and so on . so for every 9 clicks it raises the total by 1. I don't know enough Javascript to complete this ask. Below is all of my code.

```js
class ClickCount {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.triggerNode = obj.triggerNode;
    this.targetNode = obj.targetNode;
    this.resetNode = obj.resetNode;
    this.count = 0;
    this.handleClick();
    this.handleCount();
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.triggerNode.addEventListener("click", () =>
      this.handleCount({ count: this.count++ })
    );
    this.resetNode.addEventListener("click", () => this.handleReset());
  }

  handleCount() {
    this.targetNode.innerHTML = this.count;
  }

  handleReset() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.handleCount();
  }

}

const clickBlock = document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-click]");

clickBlock.forEach((block) => {
  const config = JSON.parse(block.dataset.configClick);
  const { trigger, target, reset } = config.selectors;
  const triggerNode = block.querySelector(trigger);
  const targetNode = block.querySelector(target);
  const resetNode = block.querySelector(reset);

  if (triggerNode && targetNode) {
    new ClickCount({ triggerNode, targetNode, resetNode});
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.c-block {
  margin: 50px;
}

button,
b {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.doctile {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170,0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
.vidtile {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170,0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
.button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170,0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
}
.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.button-primary {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
}

.button-secondary {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
}

.button-reset {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
  display: block;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 12px auto 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 56px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170,0.5);
}

.result {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.totaltile {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170,0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size:25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Click counter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="doctile">
  <div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset"}}'>
    <b class="result"></b>
    <button class="button button-primary" type="button">
      Document Count
    </button>
    <button class="button-reset">
      Reset
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="vidtile"> 
<div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset"}}'>
    <b class="result"></b>
    <button class="button button-secondary" type="button">
      Verified Videos
    </button>
    <button class="button-reset">
      Reset
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
  <span class="totaltile">
    <p>Total Units = 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(this.count)
      </script>
    </p>
    
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I've extended your `data-config-click`

- `resultElement` - the result node for your total units
- `weight` - being used to calculate the total with the formula `count / weight`. Ex: `27 / 9 = 3` (increase 3 for the total)

```
<div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset", "weight": 9, "resultElement": "#total-units"}}'>
```

And then add the logic to your `class ClickCount` for the total units calculation

```
increaseTotal() {
    let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
    const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight)
    currentTotal -= weightedCount
    const increasedWeightedCount = parseInt((this.count + 1) / this.weight)
    currentTotal += increasedWeightedCount

    this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
  }

decreaseTotal() {
    let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
    const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight)
    currentTotal -= weightedCount

    this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
}
```

```js
window.onload = () => {
  class ClickCount {
constructor(obj) {
  this.triggerNode = obj.triggerNode;
  this.targetNode = obj.targetNode;
  this.resetNode = obj.resetNode;
  this.weight = obj.weight;
  this.resultNode = obj.resultNode;
  this.count = 0;
  this.handleClick();
  this.handleCount();
}

increaseTotal() {
  let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
    ? 0
    : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML);
  const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight);
  currentTotal -= weightedCount;
  const increasedWeightedCount = parseInt((this.count + 1) / this.weight);
  currentTotal += increasedWeightedCount;

  this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
}

decreaseTotal() {
  let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
    ? 0
    : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML);
  const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight);
  currentTotal -= weightedCount;

  this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
}

handleClick() {
  this.triggerNode.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.increaseTotal();
    this.handleCount({
      count: this.count++,
    });
  });
  this.resetNode.addEventListener("click", () => this.handleReset());
}

handleCount() {
  this.targetNode.innerHTML = this.count;
}

handleReset() {
  this.decreaseTotal();
  this.count = 0;
  this.handleCount();
}
  }

  const clickBlock = document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-click]");

  clickBlock.forEach((block) => {
const config = JSON.parse(block.dataset.configClick);
const { trigger, target, reset, weight, resultElement } = config.selectors;
const triggerNode = block.querySelector(trigger);
const targetNode = block.querySelector(target);
const resetNode = block.querySelector(reset);
const resultNode = document.querySelector(resultElement);

if (triggerNode && targetNode) {
  new ClickCount({
    triggerNode,
    targetNode,
    resetNode,
    resultNode,
    weight,
  });
}
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.c-block {
  margin: 50px;
}

button,
b {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.doctile {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.vidtile {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 425px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.button-primary {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
}

.button-secondary {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
}

.button-reset {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, .4);
  display: block;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  margin: 12px auto 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 56px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.result {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.totaltile {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Click counter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="doctile">
      <div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset", "weight": 9, "resultElement": "#total-units"}}'>
        <b class="result"></b>
        <button class="button button-primary" type="button">
      Document Count
    </button>
        <button class="button-reset">
      Reset
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vidtile">
      <div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset", "weight": 1, "resultElement": "#total-units"}}'>
        <b class="result"></b>
        <button class="button button-secondary" type="button">
      Verified Videos
    </button>
        <button class="button-reset">
      Reset
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <span class="totaltile">
    <p>Total Units = 
      <span id="total-units">
      0
      </span>
  </p>

  </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've copied all of the code 5 times to my local machine and opened the index page and it looks like it should but, nothing happens. When I click on "Run code snippet" it works great. What if anything might I be doing wrong.

Comment: @JonBeckner how it looks like in your local? I guess you need to check how you import Javascript and styles files

Comment: My code that I uploaded works as is. The newly modified code does not

Comment: When I put the the HTML CSS and JS into VSCode it does not work. However it does work in Codepen

Comment: I tried to export the working codepen but as soon as I open it on from the saved files it does not function. the layout is perfect but the JS does nothing.

Comment: I think the problem is from local HTML. Your HTML is not ready yet, but you run scripts immediately. I'd suggest wrapping your script logic with `window.onload` (in my updated answer). Hopefully, it will help you @JonBeckner

Comment: That was the answer...thank you for your putting up with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I could export the overall total to google sheets? I could manually do this but would love to have it automated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with google sheet setup, but you can try to find google sheet API integration here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js @JonBeckner

Comment: How can I access the total in a variable I can use later?

Comment: You can add a variable `total` to `ClickCount` class and whenever you call `new ClickCount()`, you can assign a value to it like `const clickCount = new ClickCount()`, and you can access the total by `clickCount.total`

Comment: As knowledgable as I am.  I am unsure how to do this. would I add this as an obj? if so what would it look like.

Comment: ah I just found an easier way for you, you can get value directly from `document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML`. If you want to get a number value, you can parse it to a number by `Number(document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML)` @JonBeckner

Comment: If I wanted to add a minus button to my counter how would I do that? I can do that in html and css but the js is confusing me.

Comment: I just helped you to extend the logic for minus case https://jsfiddle.net/pzsj7f9n/